# Capybara-webkit unexpected behavior with url routes, returns blank page

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I encountered an issue using Capybara-webkit. A simple example code like this that should show the sign in page fails:

```
feature 'user signs in' do
  scenario 'sign in successfully', js: true do
    user = create(:user)

    visit new_user_session_url
    expect(page).to have_text 'Sign in'
  end
end
```

It gives a failure message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text 'Sign in'
    expected to find text "Sign in" in ""
```

`save_and_open_page` shows a blank page with empty `<body></body>`. Everything works fine if `js: true` is removed.

I know this spec doesn't require `js` to be set. But the specs that depend on `javascript` also fail. So this is just a sample spec.

Anybody with an explanation why Capybara-webkit behaves like this? Is it normal, an issue or there is something I have not set correctly?

[Note]
The app uses subdomains. Could it be that Capybara-webkit doesn't play well with subdomains?

Comment: What exactly is new_user_session_url returning?

Comment: `http://www.example.com/users/sign_in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from my own mistake. In my controller, I am checking for the subdomain that comes with the `request.url` using `request.subdomains`. This returns array of subdomains present before the `host` in the `url`.

In my test, I stub `ActionDispatch::Request` to accept `:subdomains` method and respond with the provided subdomain. Then, it can proceed with the verification in the controller.

Because there are places where I set the `subdomain` attribute in a route url on the fly, I was having different values for `request.subdomain` (the new one set in the url) and `request.subdomains` (the old one before setting the one in the url). So I decided to go with the new one and just split it with `.split('.')` since that is what I need to work with.

After changing that, I forgot to update the stub in the spec to change the request method to `subdomain`.

After changing it, everything works fine.

I hope this helps anyone facing this same problem. At least it will remind them to update all stubs they have if any.

**[Update]**
Apparently, the reason why I was getting different values for the 2 subdomain method was because of the stub in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup config.action_controller.default_url_options in your test environment (usually test.rb). The host specified there is used by the url helpers to build the url, and would need to be a host name that resolves to the interface capybara is running the test app on (usually 127.0.0.1) - you can check this by seeing what new_user_session_url is returning in your test code.

Comment: `config.action_controller.default_url_options` is not set. And the value of `new_user_session_url` is valid. It uses `example.com` as hostname. I will update the question to show that the app depends on subdomains heavily.

Comment: You say it works properly with new_user_session_path, but fails with new_user_session_url, the only difference there is that xxx_url includes hostname and (possibly port number) in the url -- Have you enabled `Capybara.always_include_port = true` to make sure the port number for the test app is adjusted for the url you are attempting to visit?

Comment: Surprisingly, the xxx_path fails too now. And yeah, I have `Capybara.always_include_port` set to `true`. Now I don't understand where to look into to debug this :(

Comment: If it runs fine when `Capybara.default_driver` is set to `:rack_test`. i.e. when `js: true` is removed. What I want to understand is why Capybara-webkit fails to render the page.

Comment: rack_test completely ignores the hostname/port passed in visit and just directly calls the app based on the path.  Your test logs should show what requests are making it to the app, and capybara-webkit will render whatever your app returns, so it sounds like your app is returning an empty page (are you getting the correct portion of the domain as your subdomain?)  You should probably add your Capybara config to your question and also correct the fact that it doesnt actually work with xxx_path

Comment: Thanks for your time. I figured out where the issue is. I am setting the subdomain on the fly and checking `request.subdomains` in the controller which I later changed to `request.subdomain` and split with `('.')`. After this change, I didn't update the stubbed request in the spec. It was still stubbing `request.subdomains` instead of `request.subdomain`. Changing that fixed it.